# code issue convert time in PHP

Tags: php

having issues getting code to work properly and am sure I'm just missing something.

Previously I was using the following code:

```
 echo "<td>" .date("d-M-Y H:i", strtotime($row['vertrekdatum2'])). "</td>";
```

And have recently redone my php page template so that I can just use the following format for codes:

```
<? echo "$row[vertrekdatum2]"?>
```

However, in my previous page I was formatting the date/time to be something more like:  01-Dec-2013 15:14 in the output.

I have been trying to figure out how I would do this with the above code. I have tried the following, but all give me an errors message:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in   
 /home/...../public_html/vluchtgegevens/test.php on line 108
```

I've tried
     `<? echo "date("d-M-Y H:i", strtotime($row[vertrekdatum2]))"?>`
     `<? echo "date("d-M-Y H:i", strtotime($row[vertrekdatum2]));"?>`

What am I missing?

Comment: Quotes are when you want to build/create a string. `date()` returns a string by default, so you don't need them. It should simply be: `<? echo date("d-M-Y H:i", strtotime($row[vertrekdatum2])); ?>`.

Comment: I don't know what you think double quotes mean in PHP but you are abusing them. As in many other languages, you only need quotes when you want to create a string literal.

Comment: thanks for your help. Amal your answer was close, I ended up using Nambi's from below. regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Single quotes `'` not double quotes `""` inside the date function

Do like this

```
    <?php echo date('d-M-Y H:i', strtotime($row[vertrekdatum2])); ?>  
    <?php echo date('d-M-Y H:i', strtotime($row[vertrekdatum2])); ?>
```

Comment: @DaniëlCronk  It's ok Happy coding :)

Comment: With this, single or double quotes should work. The problem was that he was echoing the whole thing as a string, when he should be just echoing the result from the date function.